# fql not retrieving albums

Tags: api, facebook-fql

I am trying to run a simple FQL query:

```
SELECT aid,name FROM album WHERE owner='user_id'
```

The problem is that for some users it does return albums, and for some (who obviously have them as I can check thru the web-site) it returns an empty set.  Maybe anyone has encountered such a behaviour and can point me where to dig?  Or maybe this is just a buggy FQL?  Any input is appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it - we found out that the problem was in the Facebook privacy settings for the specified users - there is a privacy setting which can restrict API access to the specific data of the user like photos - as it was in our case.